# Jenkins ignores proxy settings while building a job

Tags: linux, build, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I set a proxy under Plugins in Jenkins like suggested online.

I also edited the /etc/environment

```
    bash-3.2$ cat /etc/environment
    http_proxy=proxy.company.net:8080
    https_proxy=proxy.company.net:8080
    HTTP_PROXY=proxy.company.net:8080
    HTTPS_PROXY=proxy.company.net:8080
    HTTPS_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI=false
    HTTP_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI=false
```

I verfied the variables and they are available on logon.
When I start ant manualy as root via ssh, my "composer.phar" script is able to connect and download files. As soon as Jenkins starts the job (I think its the "jenkins" linux user), he waits until timeout and aborts the build. I used "su jenkins -s /bin/bash" to get a shell as "jenkins" and the env-vars are set correctly...

What can I do? Why does Jenkins ignore these ENV-Vars?

Thanks.

Comment: Add a shell script build step that runs `set`. I should expose what shell Jenkins is running, and if the variables from /etc/environment are set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get it solved. After a restart the server fails all Jenkins Jobs for some minutes... suddenly the connection to the proxy succeeds and everything works well.

Answer (score 1):

The http_proxy variables (as seen e.g. on the wget man page) require a "http://" prefix to work properly for many programs.

Jenkins on the other hand has a proxy configuration at Manage Jenkins > Plugin Manager > Advanced. This configuration overrides the environment variables.

Check [Alex' answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38759970/969483) for getting around this behavior for individual nodes/builds.